# Como restringir o acesso externo a arquivos pela url com htaccess?

Tags: apache, htaccess

Estou estudando [htacess](/questions/tagged/htacess), e encontrei [este artigo](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/confira-20-dicas-e-truques-extremamente-uteis-do-htaccess) (que ajudou em muita coisa), onde consta o seguinte:

> Digamos que você deseja **evitar que terceiros acessem determinados arquivos e pastas em seu site**. Você possui um script qualquer instalado, por exemplo, e deseja evitar que visitantes acessem sua pasta “includes”.
>
> Por outro lado, **você precisa garantir que qualquer página do site em questão possa “chamar” sem problemas os arquivos contidos nesta pasta.** Basta, então, adicionar um .htaccess com o seguinte conteúdo na tal pasta, no caso, a “includes”:

```
# Acesso restrito!
deny from all
```

A questão de acessar a listagem dos diretórios `Options -Indexes` já resolveu, mas se coloco `deny from all`, nenhum arquivo desta pasta consegue ser acessado por `submit`, mesmo que a requisição venha de uma página do próprio site.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /pastaProtegida/arquivodaPastaProtegida.php on this server.

No caso esta página é chamada por um `submit` de um `form`.

O que não entendo é que na pasta dos "scripts puros", que não não são chamadas por submit do form isso funciona, ou seja, eles são usados e não dá pra acessar digitando o caminho no navegador.

Por exemplo: se a página acima chamar um script assim:

```
<?php 
include "pastaProtegida/scriptQueVaiSerUsado.php";    
?>
```

Assim funciona, mas quando uma página chama a outra pelo `submit` não funciona... Porque? Como fazer para que as páginas de um diretório só possam ser acessadas por requisições de outras páginas do mesmo site, mas não se a pessoa digitar a url no navegador (ou mesmo clicar num link que esteja fora do site)? É póssível fazer isso apenas com htaccess (sem usar rotas ou sistema autenticação p.ex.)?

Comment: Provavelmente não está funcionando por que no submit você está fazendo uma requisição http, já no include, como é php, ele ainda está no servidor. Imagino que seja isso. Quanto a sua outra pergunta, eu já tive esse problema, aguardo fielmente para saber resposta, hehe

Comment: É, deve ser isso mesmo, e percebi que os css e js também não abrem, acho que pelo mesmo motivo... @MiguelNeto