# Como ocultar os caminhos de diretórios na url com htaccess?

Tags: apache, htaccess

Como fazer para que todas as urls do site sejam encurtadas, ocultando todos os caminhos de diretórios?

Por exemplo:

```
www.meusite.com/models/scripts/arquivo.php
www.meusite.com/view/templates/arquivo.php
www.meusite.com/view/templates/especifica/arquivo.php
```

E quero que fique sempre:

```
www.meusite.com/arquivo.php
```

Isso é possível? Como fazer? (já adiantado que li todas, ou quase todas as principais questões sobre isso aqui no site e não achei uma resposta objetiva).

> Update: O que procuro é uma regra com expressão regular que faça isso sempre, em todas as urls, na linha da resposta e dos comentários da reposta do @Miguel Neto.

Comment: Nesse caso creio eu, que você teria que colocar seus arquivos na raiz do seu projeto.

Comment: @Marconi acho que me expressei mal. No caso tenho uma url `https://www.meusite.com.br/pasta1/pasta2/pasta3/arquivo.php` por exemplo, e quero que apareça na barra de navegação apenas `https://www.meusite.com.br/arquivo.php`. Isso não é possível com htaccess?

Comment: No caso da resposta abaixo, você pode usar um regex que chegue ao resultado esperado.

Comment: A não ser que especifique o caminho para cada arquivo no `.htaccess`, ou crie padrões de nomes de arquivos como `lib_arquivo.php` que vai redirecionar para `lib/arquivo.php` não tem como fazer só com regex. Infelizmente, isso não é possível por falta de informação. Não tem como recuperar a pasta de um determinado arquivo de uma URL sem ter isso mapeado. Outra alternativa é usar uma linguagem e [implementar URL Amigável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95310/url-amigavel-dinamica/98403?noredirect=1#comment200509_98403).

Comment: Pois é @marcusagm na verdade eu estava fazendo uma confusão pra estruturar as pastas e arquivos do meu projeto... então a solução foi mudar a estrutura das pastas e colocar estes arquivos na raiz mesmo, e daí não tenho mais necessidade de ocultar os caminhos... Acho que este seu comentário é na verdade uma resposta, porque soluciona a minha pergunta ("Isso é possível?"). Se animar posta aí como resposta para que eu possa encerrar o tópico. Valeu.

Comment: Pois é imaginei, pois o caminho que estava tentando fazer sem ser especificar por htaccess arquivo por arquivo, ia resultar no caminho inverso, a URL apresentando a pasta mas o arquivo estava na raiz rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A não ser que especifique o caminho para cada arquivo no `.htaccess`, ou crie padrões de nomes de arquivos como `lib_arquivo.php` que vai redirecionar para `lib/arquivo.php` não tem como fazer só com regex.

Infelizmente, isso não é possível por falta de informação. Não tem como recuperar a pasta de um determinado arquivo de uma URL sem ter isso mapeado.

Outra alternativa é usar uma linguagem e [implementar URL Amigável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95310/url-amigavel-dinamica/98403#98403).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o .htaccess para reescrever a URL

**URL atual**

```
www.meusite.com/arquivos/arquivo.php
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^arquivo\.php$ arquivos/arquivo.php
```

**URL**

```
www.meusite.com/arquivo.php
```

Você deve colocar o .htaccess no diretório do arquivo em questão

Comment: Então, é isso mesmo, mas não tem jeito de fazer uma regra só pra todas as urls?

Comment: Tem sim, aí você terá que tomar como base a raiz dos documentos(domínio). Fazendo com regex, a lógica seria: URL(www.meusite.com/arquivos/arquivo.php), ele vai pegar o vem antes do ".php" e o que vem depois da ultima barra "/" e concatenar com o que vem antes da primeira barra "/", ficando (www.meusite.com/arquivo.php). Tem como fazer isso com regex, só não sei te dizer como exatamente, acho que já ajuda.

Comment: Ajuda sim, claro, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é o seu caso, mas também há uma boa maneira de se ocultar a listagem de arquivos do seu servidor fazendo assim:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Valeu Wallace, mas este problema já resolvi (e com esta solução mesmo), como falei [nesta outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97882/como-restringir-o-acesso-externo-a-arquivos-pela-url-com-htaccess). O que eu procuro aqui é o que @Miguel falou no comentário da outra resposta...

Comment: Então a resposta aceita foi a do Miguel? Porque estou vendo outra resposta aceita.