# Como escolher a URL da página (vice-versa)

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-core, url

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um projeto com `.NET Core Razor`, e eu estou com uma estrutura de arquivos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando no navegador eu vou para a página MenuPrincipal, a URL fica assim:

> https://localhost:44390/Menu/MenuPrincipal

Eu gostaria, para ficar mais organizado, que minha URL aparecesse da seguinte maneira:

> https://localhost:44390/Menu

Se alguém aí souber se tem alguma maneira de fazer isso, poderia me dar uma ajuda? Obrigado.

Ah, mais uma coisa relacionada... Eu tenho o link de uma url de uma página que eu ainda vou criar. O Link é esse: (não sou eu que defino este link, apenas recebo de um outro arquivo)

> https://localhost:44390/Menu/Binarios/Pesquisas/pesquisasSp1Pesquisar

Essa URL pra mim ta legal, mas tem jeito de eu criar este arquivo, com esta url, sem ter que criar uma estrutura igual a que está indicando a URL? Ou eu preciso criar toda a estrutura igual está na URL?

Comment: Está usando (ou pretende usar) MVC?

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves. Não estou usando nem pretendo usar.

Comment: Altere o nome do arquivo na pasta Menu de MenuPrincipal para Index

Comment: não ficaria legal, eu precisarei fazer isso não só com este arquivo, mas com outros também. Não vou criar uma pasta pra cada e colocar todos os arquivos com nome Index. @AlissonMarqui

Answer (score 1):

Você pode anotar o seu método no Controller com a anotação `[Route("/")]`

Exemplo:

```
[Route("menu")]
public class DistrictController : ControllerBase
{

    [Route("/")] 
    public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Alisson, é um projeto `.Net Core Razor`, não `mvc`... eu não uso Controller

Answer (score 0):

Este é o caminho que o foi percorrido até o arquivo da sua pagina web.
Como se fosse um diretório.

Para ficar da forma que vc quer, vc tem que tirar o arquivo dentro da pasta menu e renomea-lo para "Menu".

Comment: Coloque o arquivo "Menu" na pasta raiz

Comment: Sim, eu sei que este é o caminho, mas gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de deixar ele onde está(dentro da pasta Menu) e mesmo assim, a rota da url aparecer de uma outra maneira.

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho tanta experiência com esse assunto, mas já vi algo relacionado enquanto buscava sobre URL amigáveis e .htaccess

Aqui alguns links que podem te ajudar:

[Como ocultar os caminhos de diretórios na url com htaccess?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97888/como-ocultar-os-caminhos-de-diret%C3%B3rios-na-url-com-htaccess)

[url amigavel dinamica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95310/url-amigavel-dinamica/98403#98403)

[URL amigável e o google](https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/o-que-e-url-amigavel/)

Comment: Me direcionou para oque eu preciso, mas ainda não resolvi. Mas agradeço pela mãozinha rsrs